# Undo checkin in TFS using visual studio 2012: rollback will not give me my pending changes back

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, rollback

I accidentally pressed the Checkin button when I had a list of all my pending changes (in several solutions) open (and I had disabled the confirmation prompt a few years ago, have restored it now though).

I know I can do a rollback of the specific changeset, but this will not give me back my checked out items as it will just overwrite the changes of the changeset with new changes.

Does anybody know of a way to undo the checkin and get my checked out items and changes back?
Perhaps there is an extension to do a rollback, keep al the changes locally and check out those files again.

Or there is another automated way to keep al the changes and check out the files (manually checking out each file is to much work).

---

Edit

There doesn't seem to be a perfect way. For me the best solution was to 'Rollback the rollback'as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24896432/1343595

Comment: Rollback then do a get specific version of the version you just rolled back?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check-in my rolled back changeset+fixes to TFS after an emergency rollback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24896282/how-do-i-check-in-my-rolled-back-changesetfixes-to-tfs-after-an-emergency-rollb)

Comment: This question indeed looks similar. But that solution isn't what i'm looking for as I have a large changeset for several different projects. It has to be fairly easy to do a diff with the latest changeset on the server and the check out all the different files.

Comment: this question can be closed