# VS Team Services: How to amend a check in?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

For my project I use VS Team services, linked to Visual Studio 2015.

When I want to check in a new commit, I can do this:

- In solution explorer, right click on project
- Source Control -> Check In
- Enter a comment, click 'Check In'

Now I would like to amend my previous commit, since it wasn't finished completely when I checked it in, in GIT this is possible with the `git commit --amend` function.

How to do this in VS Team Services? Preferably from Visual Studio itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really, there are 2 approaches you can take with TFVC:

1. Make a second commit and don't worry about it, this is my approach for small typos, etc.
2. Rollback the changeset, and check it in. Then rollback the rollback and make additional changes and check in again. This is my approach if I totally stuff something up.
   [Related Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24896282/how-do-i-check-in-my-rolled-back-changesetfixes-to-tfs-after-an-emergency-rollb).

All you can ammend in TFVC is the Check in Comment, this can be done by viewing the change set in VS, editing the comment and pressing "Save".

Comment: Ok, will choose number 1. Do you know why this is? Since TFVC seems to be build on top of git, you'd expect the same functionality?

Comment: TFVC and Git are not related.  They were developed independently. TFS Version Control was taken from Visual Source Safe and is a SVN style centralised VCS. I've never heard of a CVCS that has ammending commits. This was something that came as part of git, and maybe other DVCS's.

Comment: TFS / VSTS Allow you to have 2 repo types Git and TFVC, but the 2 are totally different source control systems. It's just VS abstracts most of that for you.